# how do I list all files that don't end in 5-9 without changing directories

Tags: unix

I need to list all the files, from a parent folder, of 2 different directories at once. I have already tried to do `ls [directory] [directory] *[!5-9]` and `ls [directory] [directory] ?[!5-9]` but they did not work. I've tried different variations using ; and || but those don't work either

Comment: Homework tag is deprecated.  Learn regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
ls [directory] [directory] | grep [^5-9]\$
```

The caret `^` negates the range you have specified and the `\$` prevents bash from interpreting the sigil, but also makes sure it is at the end of the line.

Comment: wouldn't a ! do the same thing as a ^?

Comment: @ertang No, give a test to see why.

Comment: oh ok. I read it wrong. somehow i missed the whole `|grep` part

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
  ls [directory] [directory] | grep -v '[5-9]$'
```

Grep is used to match regular expressions. It really helps a lot

Comment: it works but my class hasn't gotten to that yet is there a way to do it without using grep?